# GridView doesn't apply css in Firefox and IE

Tags: c#, css, gridview, colors

My issue is following - i put colored text in one of my GridView cells:

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes.Add("style", "color: green");
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Some text";
```

It also colors right and bottom border of cell [4].
I tried putting black border color though CssClass on GridView, also to put BorderColor property on RowStyle in GridView properties, also to put some code, right below the upper code - a line:

```
GridView1.Attributes.Add("style", "border-color: black");
```

none of the 3 solutions color right and bottom borders.

Anyone has a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the HTML output when you apply the style attribute(s)? Is the style attribute there?

Comment: If you just want to give your cell a border and a text color, why don't you just write `Add("style", "color: green; border:1px solid black");`?

Comment: Hm, does the table have `border-collapse:collapse`?

Comment: @StevenV - I don't see my GridView in HTML! I was surprised when i saw this. This is maybe because i make GridView visible on page when i click a button. Button and GridView are in UpdatePanel, maybe that is the reason why i don't see it in HTML.

Comment: If the gridview is loaded in an UpdatePanel it wouldn't show in the HTML source. You'd need to use the web developer tools in your browser to look at what the browser has rendered.

Comment: @StevenV yeah, i eventually remembered that, but i already found a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebug for Firefox, inspect the table and look at the HTML output. you will be able to style it according to that.

```
table tr td{border:1px solid black}
```